# Makefile appending string to variable

Tags: makefile

I want to generate the command:

```
taskset -c 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14 ./myprogram
```

First try: I use echo:

```
taskset 0$(shell for n in $(shell seq 1 14);do echo ",$$n";done) ./myprogram
```

But echo gives additional trailing space between iterations

```
taskset -c 0,1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7 ,8 ,9 ,10 ,11 ,12 ,13 ,14 ./myprogram
```

,which is not recognizable for taskset function. So, I tried to append the string by my self,

```
taskset -c $(shell CORE_NUM=0; for n in $(shell seq 1 14); do CORE_NUM:=$(CORE_NUM)","$$n;done;echo $(CORE_NUM)) ./myprogram
```

However, I'm not familiar with Makefile, I got an error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: CORE_NUM:=0,1: not found
/bin/sh: 1: CORE_NUM:=0,2: not found
/bin/sh: 1: CORE_NUM:=0,3: not found
/bin/sh: 1: CORE_NUM:=0,4: not found
....
/bin/sh: 1: CORE_NUM:=0,14: not found
taskset -c 0 ./myprogram
```

Can someone help to fix it?

Comment: You would have needed to use two `$$` in front of `CORE_NUM`, as you want this to be resolved by the shell, not by make.   Also instead of `$(shell seq 1 14)`, you could have used `{1..14}`.   Having said that, Etan's answer is much better (though you can still use `{1..14}` instead of invoking a new shell).

Comment: I have tried to substitute $(CORE_NUM) with $$CORE_NUM, still the same problem.

Comment: @John , also, it seem like I cannot use expansion in this way: `taskset -c "0$$(printf ,%s {1..14})" ./myprogram`. 
`taskset: failed to parse CPU list: 0,{1..14}`

Comment: @John You **can't** use `{1..14}` by default actually. make uses `/bin/sh` for recipe lines and it doesn't support that. You would need to specify `SHELL := /bin/bash` to make that work.

Comment: Yes, sorry, the `{1..14}` is bash specific -- hadn't considred that...   Ruo, you also used `:=` and braces in `$(CORE_NUM)`, which are make-specific conventions.  Bash does not recognize these.    You should have `$(shell CORE_NUM=0; for n in $(shell seq 1 14); do CORE_NUM=$$CORE_NUM,$$n;done;echo $$CORE_NUM)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `$(shell)` here at all. There's no point. The `$(shell)` function is for running shell commands in *make* context. But you aren't in make context at this point. You are in *shell* context in the recipe so just use normal shell command substitution.

```
taskset -c "0$$(printf ,%s $$(seq 1 14))" ./myprogram
```